# How to make trigger react on specific SP only

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
create procedure UpdateIte(@iID int,@qtt int)
as begin
insert into updateItem
values(@iID,@qtt,getdate())
end
```

and

```
create procedure releseItem(@eid int,@qty int,@itemId int)
AS BEGIN
declare @no int,@qt int

select @no=qty
from Stock
where itemID=@itemID

if(@no>@qty)
BEGIN

    update Stock
    set qty=qty-@qty
    where itemID=@itemID

    select @qt=qty
    from Stock
    where itemID=@itemID

    insert into release
    values(@eid,@itemId,@qty,getdate())
    if(@qt<=10)
    BEGIN
        print'Item needs to replace'
    END

    else
        print'Success'
END
else
BEGIN
    print'Not Enough items in stock'
END
END
```

i want to create trigger, when release items that update the release table with employee id. when i create trigger it trigger with both procedures. But i want it to trigger with releaseItem. How do i do that?

create trigger CheckQty
    ON Stock
    for Update
    as begin
    declare @qty int, @emp int, @q int,@ItemId int

```
select @qty= qty, @emp=eid, @ItemId=ItemId
from inserted

select @q=qty
from Stock
where ItemId=@ItemId

if(@qty>0)
begin
    insert into releseItem
    values (@eid,@ItemId,@qty)
end
else
    rollback transaction
end
```

Comment: could you post trigger code?

Comment: print? are you sure this is mysql and not sql server?

Comment: Are you asking if you can disable a trigger within a code block? If so you may be interested in this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/disable-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 (assuming sql server)

Comment: Since you're using SPs already - do all you need within particular SP, don't create trigger at all.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You can just exececute store procedure in trigger as below.

```
create trigger CheckQty ON Stock for Update as begin declare @qty int, @emp int, @q int,@ItemId int
select @qty= qty, @emp=eid, @ItemId=ItemId
from inserted

select @q=qty
from Stock
where ItemId=@ItemId

if(@qty>0)
begin

    exec releseItem @eid, @ItemId, @qty

end
else
    rollback transaction
end
```